# Error al enviar correo a través de php

Tags: php, html

estoy realizando el diseño de un correo con una mejor presentación para su envió haciendo uso de php, el problema radica al incluir la variable $nombre en el cuerpo del mensaje, al realizar la validación en el servidor me arroja el sgte error.

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''
> ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /home/clinicae/public_html/index.php/es/send_form_email.php on line 104

```
 <?php  
    $error ='';
    //VALIDANDO NOMBRE
    if(empty($_POST["nombre"]))
    {
        $error ='Ingresa un Nombre</br>';
    }
    else
    {
     /* No necesitamos una variable transitoria para el contenido de $_POST["nombre"] */
     $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
     $nombre= filter_var($nombre, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
     $nombre = trim($nombre);
     if ($nombre == '') {
         $error .= 'El campo nombre no debe estar vacio</br>';
     } else if (preg_match("/[0-9]/", trim($nombre)) === 1) {
         $error .= 'Prohibido el ingreso de Números en el Nombre</br>';
     } else if (strlen($nombre) < 4) {
         $error .= 'Ingrese por favor un Nombre para la Consulta</br>';
     }
    }
    //VALIDANDO EMAIL
    if(empty($_POST["email"]))
    {
        $error .='Ingresa un Email</br>';
    }
    else
    {
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        if (!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            $error .='Ingresa un E-mail Verdadero</br>';
        }
        else
        {
            $email = filter_var($email,FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        }   
    }
    if(empty($_POST["mensaje"]))
    {
        $error .='Ingresa un Mensaje</br>';
    }
    else
    {
        $mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"];
        $mensaje = filter_var($mensaje,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $mensaje = trim($mensaje);
        if($mensaje==''){
            $error .= 'Nombre Vacio</br>';
        }
        else if(strlen($mensaje)<4){
            $error .= 'Ingrese al menos una palabra en el contenido del Mensaje</br>';
        }
    }   

    //CUERPO MENSAJE
    

    //DIRECCION
    $enviarA ='prueba@gmail.com' ;      
    $titulo = 'Consulta Cliente(S) Clinica Equilibrium';    
                    
    if ($error =='') 
    {
        $msg = "
        <html>
        <body>
        <p>Clinica Equilibrium</p>
        </body>
        </html>
        ";
        $encabezados = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $encabezados .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";        
        $cuerpo = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <title>Clinica Equilibrium</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        h1{
            color: #0fb4b0;
        }
        p{
            font-size: 1rem;
        }      
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>El Cliente: '.$nombre'</h1>
<p>Hola, estimados Doctores: </p>
<p>
A continuación han recibido un mensaje desde la página web con el siguiente mensaje.
</p>
</body>';
        $mensaje = wordwrap($cuerpo, 70, "\r\n");
        $cuerpo = mail($enviarA,$titulo,$mensaje,'De: '.$encabezados);          
        echo 'exito';
        // echo "<script language='javascript'>             
        //      window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
        //      </script>";
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo $error;
    }       
?>
```

Adjunto mi código para saber en que estoy fallando ya que si le quito la variable $nombre no arroja error ninguno y el correo llega tal cual se visualiza en el código.

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la línea 104?

Comment: Hay un error en la línea `<h1>El Cliente: '.$nombre'</h1>`, faltó un punto para completar la concatenación: `<h1>El Cliente: '.$nombre.'</h1>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta un punto después de nombre para que sea correcta la concatenación:

```
El Cliente: '.$nombre.'</h1>
```